# Adding new target membership to files causes "No such module" and "Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire, custom-keyboard

I'm using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON in my custom keyboard extension. I created a keyboard within a view and placed it within a view controller. I wanted to use those same files to represent the keyboard so I created a new target "Keyboard" and added Target Membership to both the keyboard extension and the project for the `BibleKeyboardView.swift` file. However, once I add Target Membership, I get the error `No such module Alamofire` and `Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code`. Even when I toggle the Target Membership for `Keyboard` off, it still has `Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code`. I open with .xcworkspace file as well.

I've tried:

- Cleaning
- Remaking the project
- running `pod install`

Anyone have an idea on what's happening?

Pictures of the file structure, target membership, and errors are below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: try with `pod install` command again and check.

Comment: this is the error with Alamofire not BibleKeyboard.swift file, Reinstall post once

Comment: Please verify alamofire pod version with your swift version. because of maximum time pod file does not support for current swift version so we have to update pod file version.

Answer (score 1):

I had a stroke of inspiration after I submitted this question.

My `Podfile` originally had

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'BibleKeyboard-iPad' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

   # Pods for BibleKeyboard-iPad
   pod 'Alamofire'
   pod 'SwiftyJSON'

end
```

but I needed to add

```
target 'Keyboard' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'

end
```